# generating documentation from annotated brightscript sources

Tags: jsdoc, roku, brightscript

I am starting working on roku, and I am searching for a tool that is able to parse annotations/comments and automatically build documentation from sources.

basically what I want is a doxygen/javadoc/jsdoc -like tool for brightscript.

Is there something available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jsdocs paired with the brighterscript-jsdocs plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/brighterscript-jsdocs-plugin

Setup instructions can be found on the project website.